# Upgrade Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard to Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I am tried to upgrade my windows server 2008 r2 standard to Enterprise but i got the below error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>DISM/online/Get-currentEdition

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Error: 87

The online/get-currentedition option is unknown.
For more information, refer to the help by running DISM.exe /?.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Can anyone advice.

Comment: Add spaces between the different command line switches. `C:\Users\Administrator>DISM /online /Get-currentEdition`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing spaces in your command. Review the syntax and try again.